# Align text at each end of a column - Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, text-align

I have a responsive table where the end column shows money figures. Currently it looks like this:
[image: Text currently]

But I want it to do this:

[image: Desired result]

There may not be any data so the `£` sign will be replace with `N/A` which should also be pulled to the right of the column.

The data is fetched from MySQL but here is a simplified snippet of my code:

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
<thead>
    <th>Reference</th>
    <th>Client</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Money</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>#1234</td>
            <td>Josh Blease</td>
            <td>Needs a new filter fixing</td>
            <td class='money'>
                <div class='text-right'>Budget: £123,456</div>
                <div class='text-right'>Value: £200,000</div>
                <div class='text-right'>Spent: N/A</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Is this content coming from the last column/td in a row? Or how do you use this?

Comment: How about show the HTML and CSS? Not much we can do without those.

Comment: Updated my question, sorry! I'm using pure bootstrap, the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Divs are useful but Ii don't think that be the best solution for this case maybe you  need to use better the table properties

http://www.usabilidad.tv/tutoriales_html/colspan_y_rowspan.asp

```html
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>Reference</th>
    <th>Client</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th colspan="2">Money</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">#1234</td>
      <td rowspan="4">Josh Blease</td>
      <td rowspan="4">Needs a new filter fixing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Budget</td>
      <td>£123,456</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value</td>
      <td>£200,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Spent</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>Reference</th>
    <th>Client</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Money</th>
  </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>#1234</td>
        <td>Josh Blease</td>
        <td>Needs a new filter fixing</td>
        <td class='money'>
            <div class='text-right'><span>Budget:</span> £123,456</div>
            <div class='text-right'><span>Value:</span> £200,000</div>
            <div class='text-right'><span>Spent:</span> N/A</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and

```
#mytable tbody tr td .text-right span{
  min-width:200px;
  max-width:300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Spans need to be set as inline-block otherwise the width properties won't take hold as they are by default inline only elements.

Setting the min and max width will force the span container to not go below or above a certain point, meaning that your other text will be forced to stay to the left of the (example) 200px mark even if your initial text (as in spent) only ends up being (again, example) 80px